# Django Error "no such column: tagging_tag.name"

Tags: python, django

I got this after installing the tagging application. I've installed it via settings.py as well as placing it on the import path so I think I've done everything right there. This is what turns up. You can see my error log [here](http://dpaste.com/224653/). I've run syncdb, so my database should be synced up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you checked output of syncdb and actually seen, that table was created? Take a look into your database and check, whether the table is created. If not, run syncdb again and if this doesn't help, create the table by hand (or drop the database and create it again from scratch).

Comment: Excellent, thanks a bunch. I deleted and recreated the database and that helped. I guess I needed to do that instead of running syncdb again after installing tagging.

Comment: Cool, glad I could help :-) Now you can hit the green button ;-)

Comment: Syncdb does not alter table so if tagging application is modifying existing table(s), it won't show up with syncdb. Take a look into South for db migration, pretty awesome. I've done countless model modifications with it and never had to drop the database. It also support reverting.